# Pipe RxJS observable to existing subject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

There is existing subject that is in use:

```
const fooSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

And there is another observable (another subject in this example):

```
const barSubject = new Subject();
barSubject.subscribe(
  value => fooSubject.next(),
  err => fooSubject.error(err),
  () => fooSubject.complete()
);

barSubject.next('bar');
```

The code works but looks clumsy.

Is there a better way to pipe (in broad sense, not necessarily using `pipe` operator) `barSubject` observable to `fooSubject`?  It looks like an operation that could be handled by the library itself.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since Subject is already an observer with methods `next()`, `error()` and `complete()` you can just subscribe it to any Observable:

```
const fooSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

const barSubject = new Subject();
barSubject.subscribe(fooSubject);

barSubject.next('bar');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant. Totally forgot that subscribe accepts observers too.

Comment: It may not be clear for some, that to subscribe a Subject to an Observable it's Observable.subscribe(Subject), not Subject.subscribe(Observable)

Comment: I guess generally you should unsubscribe somehow from `fooSubject` when `barSubject`goes out of scope. Right?
But do you have to unsubscribe from `fooSubject` if `fooSubject` does complete?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding unsubscribing after the source Observable completes, I've been using this code. It functions as expected, but I don't know if it's an "anti-pattern" or not...?

```js
const subscription = this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(finalize(() => subscription.unsubscribe()))
  .subscribe(this.mySubject$);
```

EDIT: You don't need to unsubscribe from `http.get(..)` because it's [done automatically](https://lukaonik.medium.com/do-we-need-to-unsubscribe-http-client-in-angular-86d781522b99). Therefore, with respect to the code above, the correct form would be:

```js
this.http.get(url).subscribe(mySubject$)
```

EDIT 2: A gotcha with the above code is that when http.get completes, then `mySubject$` will also complete. Now if you `.subscribe(mySubject$)` or `mySubject$.next(..)` it will not emit values. To avoid this and keep `mySubject$` hot, use this code:

```js
this.http.get(url).subscribe(r => this.mySubject$.next(r))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's possible to do this but it's an antipattern indeed. There are operators to subscribe for 1 value, and they are not needed if an observable is completed after 1 value - http likely will. Notice that the question was about subjects.

Comment: Apols for topic pollution (Google kept bringing me back here). Would this be better code? `this.http.get(url).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(mySubject$)`   Do I even need to bother with unsubscriptions when dealing with HttpClient?

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe from e.g. `http.get(..).subscribe()` because internally, upon receipt of the HTTP response, the code calls `complete()` which automatically unsubscribes all subscribers.  Source https://lukaonik.medium.com/do-we-need-to-unsubscribe-http-client-in-angular-86d781522b99

Comment: "Would this be better code?" - yes, it's better if it's not a one-off observable (i.e. emit 1 value and complete, similarly to a promise). In case http is Angular's `Http`, it was made one-off as the article says, because it can't emit multiple values