# Observable from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular I am using a Modal Directive inside a component which emits `onHide` event (EventEmitter) when modal is closed.

This component is a dialog component, its template defines a dialog, Modal Directive (*bsModal* below) makes it modal.

```
<div bsModal #modal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" [config]="{backdrop: 'static',keyboard:'false'}">
...
</div>
```

I need to Output a `close` event from component when Modal Directive emits its `onHide` event.

Here's how I am doing it:

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalDirective;
    @Output() close = new EventEmitter<any>(); // Component's close event emitter
    ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.modal.onHide.subscribe(() => {
            this.close.emit();
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Something tells me that there's a better way to achieve this, that somehow I can define component's `close` event based on directive's `onHide` observable, which will save me from subscribing directive's `onHide`.

What is that better way?

Comment: not getting you much but EventEmitter is better than observable , because if you use observable than you need to detroy/ unsubscribe it also in ngDestroy event

Comment: So, how can I relay EventEmitter from within component's template to outside?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think there's much better way to do this than you have right now. You can however make it a little shorter.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.subscription = this.modal.onHide.subscribe(this.close);
}
```

Just be aware that I'm assuming that `onHide` never completes nor errors.

Another thing to be aware of is that you need to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

```
onDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Similar question: [Pipe RxJS observable to existing subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880671/pipe-rxjs-observable-to-existing-subject)