# Pipe RxJS observable to existing subject, but not on completion

Tags: rxjs

I implemented an RxJS architecture based on the answer to this question: [Pipe RxJS observable to existing subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880671/pipe-rxjs-observable-to-existing-subject)

Later, I noticed that the observable randomly closed and I've spent a lot of time to find the cause. In the end, appeared that this snippet was causing the closing:

```
const delayed = Observable.of(arr.shift()).delay(1000);
merge(otherObs, delayed).subscribe(mySubject);
```

The `of`/`delay` observable was completing after 1 second, and it piped the completion to `mySubject`, making it unable to receive other values, including the ones sent by `otherObs` in case they arrived after the timeout.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bm5umf?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) is a StackBlitz that shows the problem.

How can I avoid `mySubject` completes, without explicitly writing the callbacks?

Comment: can you show your `otherObs` ? ... if it's not completed you would'nt receive the complete notification

Comment: @bubbles I don't think that seeing `otherObs` makes the difference, since it's the `delay` that completes. In my case, `otherObs` is a custom observable that never completes for sure, but you can imagine it as a timer if you prefer it for reproduction

Comment: `interval`, sorry, not `timer`

Comment: @bubbles I added a StackBlitz

Comment: from your stackblitz you're subscribing twice to the subject => This subject will complete on the first received complete notification (of, delay in your case)

Comment: I'm not subscribing twice, I'm piping twice. And I know that the first received complete will close it, this is what I want to avoid

Comment: `of(1).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(subject);
interval(100).subscribe(subject);` they use the same subject

Comment: this code in the other hand will not terminate `const subject = new Subject();
subject.asObservable().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
merge(interval(100), of(1).pipe(delay(1000))).subscribe(subject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, as solution I would suggest extending `Subject`, to prevent its completion as long as there are others observers listening to it, as demonstrated below:

```js
class RescrictedCompletionSubject<T> extends Subject<T>{

  public complete(): void {
    if (this.observers.length <= 1) super.complete();
  }
  
}
```

Optionally:

```js
of(1).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(mySubject.next, mySubject.error);
```

Last but not least:

```
merge(otherObs, delayed).subscribe(mySubject);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Could you explain why `repeat` works without repeating the events?

Comment: Can you add some external links to this *known issue* please ? For me this is the way `Subject` works

Comment: `@bubbles` I didn't suggest it was a bug, nor that there was any thing wrong that needed to be fixed

Comment: `@Cristian Traìna`  using `merge` there's no need for `repeat` operator, as it doesn't complete as long as there's  at least one unclosed observable.

Comment: as apposed to subscribing directly [ `of(1).subscribe(mySubject);` ] which leads to `mySubject` completion