# Pipe Observable to Subject without making it hot unneccessarily

Tags: rxjs

This question builds upon [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880671/pipe-rxjs-observable-to-existing-subject), where it is shown how to feed an `Observable` into a `Subject`. My question is similar, but I want to avoid making the `Observable` hot unless it is necessary, so that it's `.pipe()` doesn't run needlessly. For example:

```
const subject$ = new Subject();
const mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                             .pipe(map(it => superExpensiveComputation(it)));
mouseMove$.subscribe(n => subject$.next(n));
```

Because of the subscription, this will make `mouseMove$` hot, and `superExpensiveComputation` will be run for every mouse move, whether someone is listening for it on `subject$` or not.

How can I feed the result of `mouseMove$` into `subject$` without running `superExpensiveComputation` unneccessarily?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and why you don't subscribe to `mouseMove$` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) instead of `subscribe` to pass emissions to your subject:

```js
const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(
  map(it => superExpensiveComputation(it)),
  tap(subject$)
);
```

Of course you still need to subscribe to `mouseMove$` to make the data flow, but you don't need to have a subscription dedicated to passing the data to your subject.

However, you'll probably want to add [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) as not to repeat the expensive logic for multiple subscribers.

```js
const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(
  map(it => superExpensiveComputation(it)),
  share(),
  tap(subject$)
);
```

But... then in that case, do you really need a subject at all?  Unless you are going to be calling `.next()` from somewhere else, you probably don't.

Comment: Yes, I need the subject in order to call next from other places. The real code is complex, the question is as minimal as I could make it. I thought of using `tap`, but that feels so side-effecty and dirty, but I guess it's fine

Answer (score 0):

> Because of the subscription, this will make mouseMove$ hot

Wrong. The subscription doesn't change behavior of observable.

`Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')` is already hot.

Here's *naive* cold version of it.
The key takeaway, I have to resubscribe it everytime to get the latest data.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;

const mouseMove$ = of((() => {
let payload = {clientX: 0};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev) => payload.clientX = ev.clientX)
return payload;
})())

let subscriber = mouseMove$.subscribe(pr => console.log(pr));

const loop = () => {
  if(subscriber) {
    subscriber.unsubscribe();
  }
  
  subscriber = mouseMove$.subscribe(pr => console.log(pr));

  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
};

setTimeout(loop, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

> and superExpensiveComputation will be run for every mouse move,
> whether someone is listening for it on subject$ or not

Then you can get rid of `map(it => superExpensiveComputation(it))` and move that lamda to subscription so it still executes on every mouse move **but after it has been subscribed.**.